# Show that $(123) and (23\ldots n)$ together generate $A_n$ if n is even.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Show that $(123)$ and $(23\ldots n)$ together generate $A_n$ if $n$ is even. I know what to do for $(123)$ and $(12\ldots n)$ with n is odd, but how do I do this one?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $A_{n-1}$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ (consider permutations in $A_n$ that leave $1$ fixed).